# Sending ajax post through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am new to javascript and am trying to make an ajax request using jQuery but am having no luck. This is what I had so far. This seems pretty similar to many examples online so I'm not quite sure where the issues could be.  I looked at the console after sending the request and have no errors.

```
a = {};
a.name = "Steve";
a.message = "Test";

alert('start');
// submit request

$.ajax(
{
    type : "POST",
    url : "./server/shout.php",
    dataType : 'json',
    data : JSON.stringify(a),
    success: function(data) 
    {
        alert(data);
    }
});

alert('finish');
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction I'd be grateful.

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: The success function never gets executed

Comment: When you open the web inspector, the `console` only tells part of the story. Check the `network` tab and click on the request. You will then be able to see the response, which could be several different errors, `500/301/302/404`.

Comment: Do you actually have a server running? If so, is that URL valid?

Comment: Yes its valid I can hit it using the $.post() syntax

Comment: Try adding an error or completed callback as well and see if those are triggered

Comment: are you added  }); after alert('finish'); ?

Comment: And btw, `alert('finish')` would (most likely) trigger before the ajax request has finished, so don't rely on that to verify if the callback was invoked or not.

Comment: take out the `.` in the `./` and see what you get.